# How to attach a list of strings in the body of a web service request using katalon tool and groovy scripting

Tags: list, web-services, groovy, http-post, katalon-studio

** I am facing issue in passing list of Strings and attach them in the body of a delete request in katalon using groovy scripts.***

```
def request = ((findTestObject('API/phone_numbers/phone_numbers.delete_from_database',[('base_url') : base_url,('account_id') : account_id,
            ('auth_token') : GlobalVariable.auth_token, ('credentials') : GlobalVariable.credentials])) as RequestObject)   
        List<String> list_Of_Numbers= {}
        for (i in numbers)
        {
            list_Of_Numbers[i] = i
        }

        String body = """{"data":{"name":"'$list_Of_Numbers'"}}"""
        request.setBodyContent(new HttpTextBodyContent(body))
```

def response = WS.sendRequest(request)

Comment: Welcome! Please clarify your question and provide more detail, like *debug logs*.

Comment: What is the body of a delete request supposed to look like? Can you give us an example?